# Ошибка No module named 'yt_dlp' Музыкальный бот

Tags: python, pycharm

Возникла проблема с ботом, скачал его с github выбивает ошику No module named 'yt_dlp'

```
import json
import logging
import os
import re
import sqlite3
import time

import telebot
import yt_dlp
from telebot import types
```

Вроде установил этот модуль, прочитал в интернете было написано установить командой pip install -U yt-dlp
И все равно остается эта проблема,хотя модуль вроде установлен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может проблема тут? import yt_dlp подчеркивание должно быть не внизу, а по середине? yt-dlp
Надеюсь этой части кода хватит, если нет могу прикрепить полный код

Comment: А вы точно запускаете код в том же самом виртуальном окружении?

Comment: @andreymal
Ну думаю, что да, я ведь его устанавливаю через git clone

Comment: Ну, git не имеет никакого отношения к виртуальным окружениям питона

Comment: Ну и да, на скриншоте видно, что у вас установлена версия 2021.1.15 — в этой версии модуль `yt_dlp` не существует, импорт и не должен работать

Comment: @andreymal
 Понял! Спасибо!